# i want to send the mail from iphone within my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the following code to send the mail but when i click on the send button, it come out of the   app  and send the mail. 
   i dont want to come out of my application.

```
  -(IBAction) done:(id) sender 
   {
[self sendEmailTo: @"uttam.beldar@yahoo.com" withSubject: @" Question" 
    withBody:[textbody text]];
```

}

```
 - (void) sendEmailTo:(NSString *)to withSubject:(NSString *) subject withBody:(NSString *)body 

   {
      NSString *mailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@",
                        [to stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                        [subject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                        [body  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailString]];
 }


    can any one have the solution for this ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) - it's the best option for that after the release of iPhone OS 3.0 software.

If you don't want a UI, you need to implement the SMTP protocol, since I don't think there's a built in one. But there is a [google code project](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) that provides this, if you want to incorporate it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement send mail in [this easy way](http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2011/01/objective-c-send-mail-attachments/).

Tell me if you have problems.

A